# Sending Keys to Input WebElement fails as it is not an absolute path

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I'm trying to test uploading documents to a particular website using Selenium - if I run the tests locally then they seem to work fine. However if I run them via Jenkins then there's an issue. I think this may be because the test where the Java is running is linux, but the browsers are based on a windows machine. On Chrome there's a distinct error - on others they seem to just fail to load at all. Does anyone know any way to fix this? I have a feeling the exception thrown is expected behaviour within Chrome!

Stack trace for completeness:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: path is not absolute: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Tests - Chrome/console/integration-tests\src\test\resources\x\x.png
  (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 28 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
System info: host: 'SELENIUM-01', ip: '16.46.34.8', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4), userDataDir=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\scoped_dir5704_26570}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=49.0.2623.110, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 11c5faf21b8defc3047621f3800e52d2
Command duration or timeout: 146 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55'
System info: host: 'jenkins-05.ci.idolondemand.com', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-39-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4), userDataDir=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\scoped_dir5704_26570}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=49.0.2623.110, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=74aa79c8-201f-4147-9410-b0a4ea3cb66c, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 74aa79c8-201f-4147-9410-b0a4ea3cb66c
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:89)
    at com.hp.devconsole.apis.y.X.x(x.java:95)
    at com.hp.devconsole.apis.y.X.x(x.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been taken
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55'
System info: host: 'jenkins-05.ci.idolondemand.com', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-39-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:136)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: path is not absolute: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Tests - Chrome/console/integration-tests\src\test\resources\x\x.png
  (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 28 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
System info: host: 'SELENIUM-01', ip: '16.46.34.8', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4), userDataDir=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\scoped_dir5704_26570}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=49.0.2623.110, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 11c5faf21b8defc3047621f3800e52d2
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55'
System info: host: 'jenkins-05.ci.idolondemand.com', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-39-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor78.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement$1.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:335)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement.sendKeys(EventFiringWebDriver.java:358)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.KnownElements$1.invoke(KnownElements.java:64)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.SendKeys.call(SendKeys.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.SendKeys.call(SendKeys.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

## Update

This actually happens whether the slashes are all in the correct place or not - the last run had the same error:

```
unknown error: path is not absolute: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Tests - Chrome/console/integration-tests/src/test/resources/text/dog.txt
```

## Update 2

This also happens when there's no spaces in the path name e.g.

```
unknown error: path is not absolute: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/chrome_main/console/integration-tests/target/test-classes/containers/tarFile.tar
```

The code:

```
view.selectFileButton().sendKeys(getResourceAbsolutePath("text/dog.txt"));
```

Where getResourceAbsolutePath is (after trying a few different things):

```
protected String getResourceAbsolutePath(String url) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        return new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(url).toURI()).getPath();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find file with url " + url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What had happened is when some code was extracted from another project - thought to be the same as in the project I was using - the driver lost where it set its file detector to a local file detector. All that was needed was to rectify this by doing the following at the beginning of the code:

```
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```

Answer (score 0):

The error should give you a clue.  Note the path of the file that it could not find,

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Tests - Chrome/console/integration-tests\src\test\resources\x\x.png
```

has both forward slash and backslash characters.  If your test automation framework has been designed to be platform independent, then you should pass it file paths with a platform independent file separator.  "/" should work, or you can use File.separator

Comment: This actually happens regardless of whether the slashes are all correct - I'll update the question

Comment: Ok, I see spaces in the path.  Maybe that's the problem?  Could you share your line(s) of code where this exception is raised so that we can see how the file path is being passed in?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be spaces that are causing the issue either!

Comment: Wait, just reading up on this over here (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2149) I realized that I'm confused about your problem.  Is this error happening when you run on Windows?  If so, then clearly this is not an absolute path.  There is no drive letter.  There are some suggestions in https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2153