# Selenium RemoteWebDriver FileDetector Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problems with the file upload through Selenium `RemoteWebDriver`(chrome driver, up using selenium grid).

Similar to this thread: [Sending Keys to Input WebElement fails as it is not an absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36940692/sending-keys-to-input-webelement-fails-as-it-is-not-an-absolute-path)

Done some research and seems like that solution works. However, i'm getting this error: `Cannot resolve method 'setFileDetector(org.openqa.selenium.remote.LocalFileDetector)'`

I did have a required imports.
Here is my remote webdriver setup method:

```
public WebDriver SetupRemoteChromeDriver(){

Integer pageTimeout = 50;


final DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability("acceptSslCerts",true);
capabilities.setCapability("cssSelectorsEnabled", false);
capabilities.setCapability("applicationCacheEnabled", true);
capabilities.setCapability("handlesAlerts", true); //this is new to try
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "chrome");

WebDriver browser = null;
try {
    browser = new RemoteWebDriver(
            new URL("http://*ip*:4444/wd/hub"),
            capabilities
    );

    //File upload issue specific to chromedriver
    browser.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(pageTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
browser.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(pageTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

return browser;
}
```

imports to that class:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;


import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

selenium version: 2.53.1
According to the docs https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/
`RemoteWebDriver` class must have that method. Any idea why it's not imported?

Comment: yes i tried to add that, but anyway the `setFileDetector` is a method from the `RemoteWebDriver` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change line `WebDriver browser = null;` to `RemoteWebDriver browser = null;`. The variable `browser` is defined with type `WebDriver` which does not have the specified method.